# Escaping piped output between commands

Tags: bash, pipe

I use the below command to delete changed files sometimes when using hg.

```
hg status -n | xargs rm
```

I have come across an problem where if the output of

```
hg status -n
```

contains any file paths with spaces in the file will not be found. Usually i would quote or escape spaces in file names but im not sure how to do this with piped output. Any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: Did any of these answers help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell both commands to use NUL as the delimiter:

```
hg status -n0 | xargs -0 rm
```

---

Also be careful: the `-n` option will print even files Mercurial doesn't know about.

Maybe you want this instead?

```
hg status -mn0 | xargs -0 rm
```

---

Also, don't forget about [`hg revert`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Revert) or [`hg purge`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension).  Maybe they do what you want, e.g.

```
hg revert --all --no-backup
```

or

**.hgrc**

```
[extensions]
hgext.purge=
```

**shell**

```
hg purge
```

Comment: +1 NUL is the file separator of choice for people who don't want surprises.

Comment: +1 using NUL as the delimiter works great thanks! Sometimes i find it useful to throw a `grep` in there and delete a subset of files - say when I accidentally created a load of ***.orig** for example - which is why `revert` or `purge` does not fit my purpose (looking at `hg help revert` i see I could use `-I`. Well now I have two ways to do something and i learnt something new!)

Comment: See `grep -z` for how to filter null-delimited output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have `hg` installed. So I will do it with `ls`:

```
$ touch 'file A' 'file B'

$ ls -1
file A
file B

$ ls | xargs rm
rm: cannot remove `file': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `A': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `file': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `B': No such file or directory

$ ls | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm

$ ls
```

Comment: does not seem to work. Still gives error due to non-escaped path **rm: folder name/test: No such file or directory**

Comment: what does `hg status -n` return?

Comment: I only test it when using `ls`

Comment: it returns similar as ls -1, only a list of files (with paths)

Comment: it would be good if tr ' ' '\ ' would result in escaped spaces but im obv using it wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Let xargs handle that with the `-I` option:

```
hg status -n | xargs -I FileName  rm FileName
```

`-I` increases the safety, but reduces the efficiency as only one filename at a time will be passed to 'rm'

An example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" one "2 two" "three 3 3" | xargs printf "%s\n"
one
2
two
three
3
3


$ printf "%s\n" one "2 two" "three 3 3" | xargs -I X printf "%s\n" X
one
2 two
three 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside `-0`, newer `xargs` has option `-d` which can help you doing such things:

```
<command returning \n-separated paths> | xargs -d \\n rm -v
```